# pg-promise creating column error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

```
var name = req.body.name;
db.any('alter table "houseList" add  $1 text', [name])
```

I tried to add a new column to database host on **heroku** using the above code in **nodejs** but I keep getting this error :

> error: syntax error at or near "'haha'"

'haha' is the value inside name, anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using invalid escaping for the column name, as a regular string variable.

Any schema/table/column name are referred to as SQL Names, and must be escaped using `""`.

Within [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) that means you must use its [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names) support, with `:name`: or `~` modifier.

```
db.any('alter table "houseList" add  $1:name text', [name])
```

or

```
db.any('alter table "houseList" add  $1~ text', [name])
```

Also, if you sure that you are only using simple names, i.e. no white spaces, no capitals, then you can use the name directly, unescaped, which means using the [Raw Text](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#raw-text), via modifier `:raw` or `^`. But generally, it is not recommended, i.e. escaping the names is recommended as safer ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @JienanTang if it answers your question, then please accept it, by clicking on the tick mark against the votes counter.